# Group into a list a dataset based in a repeated column in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, pandas-datareader

I have a dataframe imported with pandas from excel with a format like this:

```
df = pd.read_excel('excel_file.xlsx')

data = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])


A    B   C    D   E
12  bob  32  abc 123
12  jan  34  fbc  23
14  jan  32  ac  133
12  cat  32  abc 123
```

I would like to group them by the column B so the output would come as:

```
list[0] = [[12  bob  32  abc 123]]
list[1] = [[12  jan  34  fbc  23][14  jan  32  ac  133]]
list[2] = [[12  cat  32  abc 123]]
```

I've tried using duplicated function with no success

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
lst = [d.values.tolist() for (k,d) in df.groupby('B', sort=False)]

# check
for i in range(len(lst)): print(lst[i])
```

Output:

```
[[12, 'bob', 32, 'abc', 123]]
[[12, 'jan', 34, 'fbc', 23], [14, 'jan', 32, 'ac', 133]]
[[12, 'cat', 32, 'abc', 123]]
```

Comment: Could you please help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62069465/match-lists-and-get-value-of-one-column-based-on-values-of-other-columns-from-da Thanks.